# Tweedle battle in level 10

Tags: vim-adventures

I am stuck on this:

[image: VIM adventures level 10]

And these are the keys I have available:

[image: keymap]

Comment: It might be helpful to also include what this level is asking you to accomplish.  Some users are familiar with vim but not that game.

Comment: Well this is solved appending to a register


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497958/how-to-use-vim-registers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you yank or delete, contents are saved to the registry. At your disposal you can save to a specific register by prefixing with a `"a`,`"b`,`"c`, etc. You also have the ability to append to a specific register by using the register's capital form instead of the lowercase one. Example, where `*` indicates were the cursor is located:

```
battle *tweedle paddle                         command:"ayw
```

typing `:reg` will show us that in register `a`:

```
"a    tweedle
```

notice that there is a space after `tweedle` since we grabbed with `w`. Now if we move the cursor to battle (perhaps with `b`):

```
*battle tweedle paddle                         command:"Ayw
```

register `a` now includes:

```
"a    tweedle battle
```

you can then paste the result with `"ap` to yield: `tweedle battle`. notice that there will be a trailing space.